# How to implement global modals using Svelte SPA Router?

Tags: svelte

I'm using `svelte-spa-router` library for my Svelte routing needs. I want to create a global modal component that can be opened on any page via a URL path.

For example, in Angular, there is a concept of auxiliary routes with named outlets, which allows you to open a modal from any place in the app on top of your main component outlet.

Is there a way of achieving something similar to the Angular case above in Svelte using `svelte-spa-router`?

Comment: Question is underspecified, this statement is not true at all in general: "you must explicitly implement the modal component inside your parent component".

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my comment to be less presumptuous.